# How to export a 16bit image from QGIS via command line?

Tags: qgis, command-line

I export portions of a height map from Qgis using the command line. The options are path, resolution and extents, but it exports an 8 bit image. I am getting terracing because of this. Is there a way to export a 16bit image or a plugin to overcome this?

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS-2~1.1\bin\qgis --project Z:\Projects\Glacier\QGIS\Glacier.qgs --snapshot Z:\Projects\Glacier\Images\Glacier_32km_02.png --width 4096 --height 4096 --extent 280500,5380000,312500,5412000

Answer (score 2):

The `--snapshot` command line option is a kind of screenshot of the canvas, delivering a 24-bit (3x8) RGB image. Since greyscales are displayed in RGB with R=G=B value, you only get 255 shades of grey. I'm not sure if pseudocolour rendering is able to use more values.

The only way to export images with finer values is to use GDAL with

```
gdal_translate -ot Int16 -srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize -outsize xsize ysize src_dataset dst_dataset
```

on the datasource.